# PHP. Removing part of the array

Tags: php, arrays

It is necessary to remove part of the array. Here is an example of an array:

```
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three [3] => four [4] => five )
```

The variable can be based on one of the following values ​​in the array.
Suggests there is 'three'. Need to take one, two and everything else removed.

Is there any standard methods, or a good solution that would not need to use a loop?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) for that

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 1, -1);
// $input is now array("red", "yellow")
```

Comment: for the question you also need to array_search() to find the offset http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php and omit length

Comment: @Grim I'm sorry, I do that sometimes :-)

Comment: What do you think about this version of the solution - http://www.askdev.ru/a/19557 ?

Comment: $=array_search will always be true even if not found. $i however will be false. look at my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a loop, you could use array_splice.

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, $varaible, -1);
// $input is now array("red", "yellow")
```

Answer (score 4):

This will use @JeroenMoons array_splice but will do the array_search I suggested too

```
function reduce_my_array($array, $value)
{
    // look for location of $value in $array
    $offset=array_search($value, $array);

    // if not found return original
    if($offset===false) return $array;

    // remove from the found offset to the end of the array
    return array_splice($array, $offset+1);     
}
```

Note:
array_search returns the INDEX which can be 0
array_splice uses number of entries as the offset
so for your example with numerical indexes 0 to ... you need to tell array splice index+1